# Query data from multiple tables in sequence

Tags: sql-server

Item price will be retrieved from multiple price tables. Each item’s price might not on all tables. Query sequence is based on table priority. Query will stop when price is available.

For example: Price tables have T1, T2, and T3 and table query sequence and priority is T1, T2 and T3.

T1 table records

```
Item, Price
I1, $11
I3, $13
I4, $14
```

T2 table records

```
Item, Price
I2, $21
I3, $23
I5, $25
```

T3 table records

```
Item, Price
I1, $31
I2, $32
I6, $33
```

Result:

```
Item I1 is $11, I3 is $13, 
 and I4 is $14.
```

It will be retrieved from T1 which is the first priority table. Since price is available in T1, it will not search T2 and T3.

Item I2 and I5 will be from table T2.
They are not available in first priority table T1 and query moves to second priority table T2.

Item I6 will be from T3.
Because I6 is not in T1 and T2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
; with item as
(
    select item from T1
    union
    select item from T2
    union
    select item from T3
)
select    item  = i.item,
          value = coalesce(v1.value, v2.value, v3.value)
from      item i
left join T1 v1  on i.item  = v1.item
left join T2 v2  on i.item  = v2.item
left join T3 v3  on i.item  = v3.item
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
create table #item1(
    item int,
    value int
)

insert into #item1 values
(1,1),
(2,2)

create table #item2(
    item int,
    value int
)

insert into #item2 values
(1,10),
(2,20),
(3,30)

create table #item3(
    item int,
    value int
)

insert into #item3 values
(1,100),
(2,200),
(3,300),
(4,400)

;with cte as (
    select *, t=1 from #item1
    union all
    select *, t=2 from #item2
    union all
    select *, t=3 from #item3
),
cte1 as (
    select
        *,
        rn = row_number() over ( partition by item order by t )
    from
        cte
)
select
    item, value
from
    cte1
where
    rn = 1


drop table #item1
drop table #item2
drop table #item3
```

Answer (score 1):

ok without creating tables (temporary or otherwise):

```
select
 M.item  --Select unique item from Master list
 ,coalesce(
  (select price from T1 where T1.item = M.item),
  (select price from T2 where T2.item = M.item),
  (select price from T3 where T3.item = M.item)
 )  --Cascade of prices per table
from 
  (select * from T1
  union
  select * from T2
  union 
  select * from T3) M  --Creating Master list of items and prices
group by item  --ensuring that we only pull unique items
```

I thought this was an interesting question and knew it could be done in one query.  The other answers are great too!  Just spicing it up

Comment: Nice try. Although, sub queries in select clause is not a good idea for performance. Check your execution plan. ;-)  P.S. remove the `,` before `coalesce`.

Comment: Result is exactly I need.  P.S. ',' is required before 'coalesce' on SQL Server 2014

Comment: @YellowLarry The original code was `select  M.item,,coalesce`